# Convert from non pointer to pointer

Tags: c++

I have a function that looks something like

```
foo(object& obj) {

}
```

inside this function I need to call another function like this:

```
foo(object& obj) {
    bar(pointer to obj);
}
```

the bar function takes a pointer to the object as an argument. Could some help I can do convert from non pointer to pointer?

Comment: -1 because it's ridiculous to ask on SO about the basicest basics of the language. That's what C++ books are for.

Comment: This is indeed a very basic programming question, but a legitimate one, and reasonably well formulated.  There are no requirements on SO about the "level" of the question. I'm upvoting to put it back in the queue.

Answer (score 5):

That what `&` is for, the "address of" operator.

```
bar(&obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

Call `bar` with the address of `obj`:

`bar(&obj);`

Answer (score 0):

Call as follows

bar(&obj);

Comment: Can you add some additional context and explanation for why this is the answer?